# How to always open certain app links in Chrome without prompt

Tags: macos, google-chrome

tl;dr: I want to automatically open certain app links, such as Zoom meeting or Mac App Store links, without being prompted to confirm first.

I recently replaced my MacBook, and Google Chrome behaves differently on my new one when opening app links, e.g., Zoom.us: it no longer offers the option to "Always open these types of links in the associated app".

**Before:**

[image: Before (checkbox)]

**Now**

[image: After (no checkbox)]

I don't know what version of Chrome I was running before (though I'm pretty sure it was up-to-date at the time--a couple of weeks ago). I use Chrome Sync, so my extensions and settings should be substantially the same.

Is there a way to get back the previous functionality and make Chrome open certain apps automatically without prompting for confirmation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tried and tested technique for macOS:

1. Have Chrome version > 79
2. Run the following command in terminal ​

   ```
   ​defaults write com.google.Chrome ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox -bool true
   ```
3. Quit Chrome
4. Restart Chrome

Comment: This fixed it for me

Comment: `defaults write com.brave.Browser ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox -bool true` for anyone using the Brave browser.

Comment: `defaults write company.thebrowser.Browser ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox -bool true` for anyone using Arc browser

Answer (score 2):

As of Chrome 79, you can edit use a custom policy to get this behavior back:  https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox

@abhishek-ranjan answer provides the way to do it on macOS.

On Windows:

1. Open regedit
2. Either under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (for everyone using the computer) or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (only the current user), create the following key(s) as necessary: `Software\Policies\Google\Chrome`
3. Create a REG_DWORD named `ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox` and set the value to 1
4. Restart Chrome

If you want a regedit script to do this, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1013598#c24

Answer (score 0):

It is a known "bug" but at the same time it's not a bug it really is a security feature Google rolled out.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=982341